# Pull to refresh in Apple Watch app in Swift

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I see a pull to refresh in the Apple Watch mail app, but I don't see how to implement such a scenario. Kindly give some insight into how to achieve pull to refresh in Apple Watch app in Swift.

Thanks...

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you want to get answer to your questions, try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and reformulate your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a pan gesture recognizer to your Interface Controller and then you can write the code for refreshing your data.

You have to add the gesture recognizer to your InterfaceController in InterfaceBuilder, then connect an Action to it. Have a look at [Apple's WKInterfaceCatalog example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/WKInterfaceCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html), especially the GestureDetailController class and Gestures scene in Interface builder.

You can decide to use a Swipe gesture recognizer or Pan gesture recognizer.

The IBAction for Swipe gesture recognizer is:

```
@IBAction func swipeRecognized(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    //update your UI
}
```

And for the Pan gesture recognizer:

```
@IBAction func panRecognized(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let panGesture = sender as? WKPanGestureRecognizer {
        //Update your UI
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for watch app and it is InterfaceController that we have. Could you please help your statement with a piece of code for Watch app?

Comment: See my updated answer. Since you didn't include any code in your question, I can't help you with how to update your UI, but now you should be able to get started with your pull to refresh funcitonality.

Comment: Hi David.... Firstly, it isnt possible to add a gesture recognizer to interfacecontroller. Secondly, I have an WKInterfaceTable which I have to pull down to make a call. And the feature should just look like the pull to refresh that happens in iPhone when pulling the table down.

Comment: Have you even looked at the sample code I have linked? Apple introduced gesture recognizers to WatchKit in watchOS3. Have a look at [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkgesturerecognizer). If you create your own loading indicator, you can easily create a pull down to refresh feature just like in Mail.

Comment: The scroll on the Interfacetable and the gesture recogniser in the interface controller are not being distinguished when gesture recognisers are added. Any help here?

Comment: Let me break it for you. I have an InterfaceController. An InterfaceTable is added into it. Now I add a WKPanGestureRecognizer to the table from the object library in the storyboard. This WKPanGestureRecognizer is connected with the respective InterfaceController class. The WKPanGestureRecognizer method is being called but the scroll of the InterfaceTable doesn't happen.

Comment: That was somewhat expected. You could try adding the gesture only to individual cells, but I am not sure if your individual cells have enough height for the gesture to work. Sadly most methods that could be used to achieve this are unavailable on the Watch. Apple might be using a private framework to achieve the pull to refresh.

Comment: Thanks David.... If you get anything on this. Please don't forget to post here...

Comment: Sure. However, I would suggest you to focus on other ideas at the moment. Sadly, Apple is strongly limiting what developers can do on the Watch and there's no sign of any changes coming in watchOS4 that would suggest this functionality, so it might take a while.